# How to catch laravel controller exceptions

Tags: php, exception, laravel-5

I'm new to Laravel (we're using 5.0 at work). Right now, when we respond to an API request in a Controller, we are rewriting the same code over and over to respond to unauthorized actions. For example,

```
public function getUsers(){
  if (Entrust::can('users.view')){
    $users = Users::get();
    return response()->done($users, 200);
  } else {
    return response()->unauthorized('users.view');
  }
}
```

It gets more and more complicated if we have different permissions that can allow an API request to succeed.

I'd like to simply throw an exception of some sort if the user cannot perform the API request. For example,

```
public function getUsers(){
  require('users.view'); // throws an UnauthorizedException if current user doesn't have 'users.view' permission

  $users = User::get();
  return response()->done($users, 200);
}

public function someOtherMethod(){
  if (!Entrust::can('permission1') && !Entrust::can('permission2')){
    throw new UnauthorizedException(['permission1', 'permission2']);
  }

  // some other stuff
}
```

But I don't know what code calls the API function, nor where to wrap that call in a try/catch. It's easy enough to code the UnauthorizedException, and easy to transform it into json, but where do I put the handler? As I said, I'm new to Laravel, and I don't know how it handles these exceptions.

Ideally, whatever solution I find, I'd like to extend it to other exceptions so we can have consistent json responses based on common exceptions.

Comment: I'm just beginning to dig into Laravel 5, but I would look at Middleware if this is something that is being run on multiple routes.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed (I got it working). If you add an answer to this effect I'll accept it, and comment with the exact steps I took.

Comment: Done - glad you got it working!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of repeating your code, take a look at implementing the authorization check with Middleware.